# lme function for mixed models for dichotomous variables: Singularity in backsolve at level 0, block 1

Tags: r, statistics, regression, lme4, mixed-models

I am adjusting a fixed effects model considering some covariates. Regarding the specification of the model, two of these covariates are nested and have fixed effects. See that the following error below is happening.

```
library(nlme)
library(lme4)

dados$VarCat=as.factor(dados$VarCat)
dados$VarX5=as.factor(dados$VarX5)
dados$VarX6=as.factor(dados$VarX6)

modelANew <- lme(log(Resp)~log(VarX1)+log(VarX2)+(VarX3)+(VarX4)+VarX5/VarX6 ,random = ~1|VarCat, 
                 dados, method="REML")

Error in MEEM(object, conLin, control$niterEM) : 
  Singularity in backsolve at level 0, block 1
```

Variable X6 is a dichotomous variable. This seems to me to be interfering with the convergence or estimation of the model. How can I solve?

Comment: Looks like it works when using `lmer` instead: `lmer(log(Resp)~log(VarX1)+log(VarX2)+(VarX3)+(VarX4)+VarX5/VarX6 + (1 | VarCat), data=dados)`

Comment: I probably should have closed this as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50505290/singularity-in-backsolve-at-level-0-block-1-in-lme-model?rq=1 (but I already voted to close/migrate to CrossValidated)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your data are unbalanced in a way that makes the fixed-effect model rank-deficient (or multicollinear, if you prefer). When you include `X5/X6` you are stating that you want to estimate effects for all combinations of `X5` and `X6`. However:

```
with(dd, table(VarX6,VarX5))
     VarX5
VarX6   A   B   H IND   Q   S   T
    0   2   9  94 155   0   1  15
    1   0   0   0   0   8   0   0
```

Only `VarX5=Q` is ever measured at the `VarX6=1` level, and it's never measured at the `VarX6=0` level. This means the `VarX6` variable, and its interaction with `VarX5`, are redundant information.

As pointed out in the comments, if you run this in `lme4::lmer()` it will automatically drop the redundant columns for you, with a message:

```
library(lme4)
m2 <- lmer(log(Resp)~log(VarX1)+log(VarX2)+(VarX3)+(VarX4)+
                     VarX5/VarX6 + (1|VarCat),
                 dd, REML=TRUE)
```

> fixed-effect model matrix is rank deficient so dropping 7 columns / coefficients

You can find out which columns it dropped via `attr(getME(m2,"X"), "col.dropped")`.

Alternatively, if you fit it in `lm()` (I know you want to fit a mixed model, but this is a good diagnostic) you'll see that it doesn't complain, but it automatically sets all of the redundant coefficients to `NA`:

```
m3 <- lm(log(Resp)~log(VarX1)+log(VarX2)+(VarX3)+(VarX4)+
                     VarX5/VarX6, data=dd)
coef(m3)
    (Intercept)      log(VarX1)      log(VarX2)           VarX3           VarX4 
     0.46921538      0.79476848     -0.45769296      1.85386835     -2.78321092 
         VarX5B          VarX5H        VarX5IND          VarX5Q          VarX5S 
    -0.04677216      0.21896140      0.24584351     -2.00226719      0.32677006 
         VarX5T   VarX5A:VarX61   VarX5B:VarX61   VarX5H:VarX61 VarX5IND:VarX61 
     0.17474369              NA              NA              NA              NA 
  VarX5Q:VarX61   VarX5S:VarX61   VarX5T:VarX61 
             NA              NA              NA
```

This question is very similar to [Singularity in backsolve at level 0, block 1 in LME model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50505290/singularity-in-backsolve-at-level-0-block-1-in-lme-model?rq=1) . When you have unbalanced designs like this, "what to do about it" is not a question with a single simple answer.

- you could remove terms from the model yourself (e.g. in this case you can't really estimate anything about `VarX6`, since it is completely redundant with `VarX5`, so replace `VarX5/VarX6` in your model with `VarX5`.
- you could use a function such as `lmer` that can automatically remove terms for you

What you *can't* do is actually estimate `VarX5/VarX6` - your design just doesn't include that information. It's a little like saying "I want to estimate the effect of car colour on speed, but I only measured red cars".